# Create a curved window

Tags: java, graphics2d

I'm just starting to look into Graphics in Java and I was wondering how you would go about drawing the attached image (Can't upload images) ? I am mainly looking for the top curved part

I'm looking to create a basic curved window with various Rect inside.

I'm just starting out with Java so this is what I have at the moment (this creates the structure I need but obviously I need the top part to curve)

```
static void drawFlag(Graphics2D g){
   g.setRenderingHint(
   RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING,
   RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);

   g.setColor(Color.white);
   g.fillRect(0,0,120,220);
   g.setStroke(new BasicStroke(2));
   g.setColor(Color.black);
   g.translate(0,70);

   for(int i=0;i<5;i++){
      for(int x=0;x<11;x++){

         g.drawRect(20*i,20*x,20,20);

      }
   } 
}
```

Comment: If you can't post an image, upload it somewhere and post a link instead. I imagine it's quite important to your question.

Comment: What have you tried so far?  What *specific* problems are you having?  SO is not a code-writing service; you can't just state what you need and expect people to write it for you, but if you are having problems with code that ***you*** are writing, we'll be happy to help you solve them.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/991074/swing-how-to-make-non-rectangular-windows-with-soft-borders

Comment: If you want a curved "window" that's an internal window, this is possible. Otherwise, it's going to be very hard... Probably impossible, as a consequence of how desktop OSes have implemented windowing and events (x,y,width,height)

Comment: I've edit the post and here's the link to an image http://tinypic.com/r/15r0g3l/8